# Null Pointer exception trying to modify the typeface of a listview dynamically in Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a small piece of code that is a ListActivity class

Then I dynamically populate this list using SimpleAdaptor. Each list row has 3 textviews

Now I want to change the Typeface of the text in this ListView, but when I am trying too do so, I am getting a null pointer exception. Can anybody help please?

Following is the code

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import  android.widget.TextView;


public class Test extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        // final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

     // Create the array adapter to bind the array to the listview
        SimpleAdapter notes = new SimpleAdapter( 
                this, 
                list,
                R.layout.list_row_view,
                new String[] { "line1","line2","line3" },
                new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2,R.id.text3 }  );
                setListAdapter( notes );

                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(),"tahoma.ttf");
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

                tv.setTypeface(tf);


      HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String> ();
      item.put( "line1","A" );
      item.put( "line2","B" );
      item.put("line3","C");
      list.add(item);

     HashMap<String,String> item1 = new HashMap<String,String> ();
    item1.put( "line1","A" );
     item1.put( "line2","B" );
     item1.put( "line3","C" );
     list.add( item1 );
}

}
```

The line

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

throws Null pointer exception

Comment: When you say that line throws an NPE, do you mean that line specifically or something further down the stack in the findViewById call?

Comment: Can we see the offending xml layout file?

Comment: @johusman I will correct this here, actually the line that throws NPE is 

tv.setTypeface(tf);

This is because the following line returns null
  
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1); 

@Peter following is the the two XML layouts being used

main.xml

Comment: list_row_view.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView style="@style/TopRowTextStyle" 
          android:id="@+id/text1"/>
                         
     <TextView style="@style/BottomRowTextStyle" 
          android:id="@+id/text2" />
     
     <TextView style="@style/BottomRowTextStyle1" 
          android:id="@+id/text3"/>                  
 </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that the line you cite throws the exception. More likely, it comes when you try to use the `TextView`, which does not exist.

You will have to create a custom subclass of `SimpleAdapter` and override `setViewText()`, or use a `ViewBinder`, and customize each `TextView` for each row.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will correct it here

It is actually the following line that throws NPE 
 tv.setTypeface(tf);
and this is because the following line of code returns null

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

Now, can you help me to figure out why this line returns null and what could be best way to get control of the textview being referred here?

Thanks

Comment: @Musertech: Please read http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf to learn about customizing adapters. Now, that book excerpt does not cover `SimpleAdapter`, because I don't use it, but it will give you the "big picture" of how `AdapterView` works, Then, re-read my answer again, particularly the last sentence. You have many `TextViews` needing to be adjusted, each in a row of your list, not just a single `TextView` needing to be adjusted in the activity, the way your code is presently written.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem too,  you can try surrounding the part where you add the font with try & catch block to catch a null pointer exception, so, in my case,

```
Typeface comingsoon = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "ComingSoon.ttf");
```

becomes

```
try{
    Typeface comingsoon = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "ComingSoon.ttf");
}
catch(NullPointerExecption e){
     //...
}
```